# LaTeX table help

Tags: tables, multicol, multirow

Does anyone have or can derive any LaTeX code of the form of this tricky table? Thank you

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|cc||c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c||}{\multirow{2}{*}{Word}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Word}\\
\cline{3-5}
& & 1 & 2 & 3\\
\hline
\multirow{5}{*}{Word} & \multicolumn{1}{|c||}{1} & & &\\
\cline{2-5}
& \multicolumn{1}{|c||}{2} & & &\\
\cline{2-5}
& \multicolumn{1}{|c||}{3} & & &\\
\cline{2-5}
& \multicolumn{1}{|c||}{4} & & &\\
\cline{2-5}
& \multicolumn{1}{|c||}{5} & & &\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) This is a fairly standard table. If you search on TeX.SX for "table" you will find many similar examples (for example, see the link below). Please try something yourself and if you get stuck post a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to explain where you are getting stuck. Asking people to do everything for you is a little OTT.

Comment: @Andrew I've been trying for hours and its not so simple because of the 2 sets of multicolumns under the "c" and the 5 sets of rows under the "b". That's why I've posted on here for help

Comment: You don't even give us what you *do* have.

Comment: @SeanAllred look now

Comment: Please don't use vertical lines, it looks quite ugly. I had prepared a small example for you to continue but the question was closed.

Comment: @user225927 I second Alenanno comment. Try to avoid using that much lines in your table design. Here is a [little example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B10qtxezNdNOc1lkYmNTcWM2WXM/view?usp=sharing) I was preparing with booktabs for you when the question was closed.

Answer (score 1):

This template should be easy to continue.

```
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|l|*{15}{c|}}
\hline
&&\multicolumn{15}{c|}{c}\\
\cline{3-17}
a&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{b}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{d}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{e}&
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{f}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{g}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{h}\\
\cline{3-17}
&&i&j&k&l&m&n&o&p&q&r&s&t&u&v&w\\
\hline
&3&28&29&30&  &&& &&& &&& &&\\
&4&31&32&33&  &&& &&& &&& &&\\
x&5&34&35&36&   &&& &&& &&& &&\\
&6&37&38&39&  &&& &&& &&& &&\\
&7&40&41&42&  &&& &&& &&& &&\\
\hline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

[image]